# Active on all the routes of a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used link_to_active gem to add the "active" class based on the current url. My requirement is, say for example:

Student Resource has:

```
/students
/students/new
/students/id
/students/id/edit
```

My usage of link_to_active : is

```
<%= link_to "Students", students_path, class: "list-group-item", active_on: students_path%>
```

obviously students_path coincides only with /students but what if I want keep this link active when i visit the subsequent links as mentioned above. How do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you take a look at this gem https://github.com/comfy/active_link_to, it can match on controller levels.